# How to prevent Chrome's aggressive caching from interfering with PWA

Tags: android, google-chrome, caching, progressive-web-apps

Initially, I couldn't get my PWA to update **at all** without manually clearing the cache and site files in Chrome.

I increment the cache name each time I need to put an update down the pipe.

I have added `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, public"` in my `.htaccess` file, which improved things a bit.  It seems to update the app after two launches on some devices.  Samsung devices (with that awful Samsung shell browser) still need to clear cache/files before it updates.

I can get it working on the desktop with a CTRL+F5 hard refresh, so it's not the service worker.

How can I ensure that my PWA always fetches the latest files when relaunched?

Comment: Make sure that you also load the files with `?number=x` behind the urls, this forces to load them again when you increase `x`.

Comment: @BasvanStein: will try that, thanks